# Phpunit behaves differently on different machines

Tags: php, phpunit

I wrote a few PHPUnit tests for my PHP application. I am working on two development machines that synchronize the entire development filesystem, and there is an automatic testing system that runs the tests on a clean svn checkout.

Now, something weird is going on. One of the development machines runs Ubuntu linux 10.10, PHP 5.3.3, phpunit 3.4.6 which I later upgraded to 3.4.14. When I run phpunit on each single test, all tests pass. When I run phpunit on my xml configuration file that just runs them all, using `phpunit --configuration=phpunit.cfg`, the last test case fails, and a `Class myClass not found` error is returned. This class is inside a file that is loaded using `require_once`. Upgrading phpunit made no difference.

***edit:*** I have the feeling that the list of files PHP includes using `require_once` is not reset on my linux box, but the classes are actually lost, that is, it thinks it has 
already included `myclass.php` while the class inside is not loaded.

Now, the other machine is running Mac OS X Snow Leopard 10.6.5, PHP 5.3.3 and phpunit 3.4.3. If I run the unit tests there individually, no errors occur, just as on the linux box, but when I run the tests using the xml configuration, no errors occur either. We also have an auto testing environment running linux 10.4 LTS, PHP 5.2.6 and phpunit 3.4.9. Also no errors.

All systems use exactly the same files, so there is no difference in the source code or tests. Also the phpunit.xml is the same.

I feel completely in the dark here. How can I figure out what the problem may be?

Both the linux development machine and the macbook are running PHP 5.3.3. The autotest machine is runing 5.2.6

Comment: Ah! Forgot to mention. All of the 3.4 branch. Mac: 3.4.3. (Working fine.) Autotest: 3.4.9. (Also working fine.) Linux: 3.4.6 and 3.4.14. (Both giving the same issue) I don't expect the issue to be absent in 3.4.3, appear in 3.4.6, be solved in 3.4.9 and reappear in 3.4.14.

Comment: If it were any other type of error, I would suspect that a previous test is interfering with a later test. This can happen if one test alters a global or static variable that a later test depends upon. Is it possible that this is happening, and it's causing a different code path to execute that needs `myClass` that isn't executed if you run that test in isolation?

Answer (score 1):

Two things to watch out for:

- The include path in the PHP config on both machines
- That there isn't another copy of the class file sitting around in your homedir or the `cwd` of the script. Usually `.` will be in the include path for PHP and rogue copies of files can cause problems like this

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible that it isn't PHPUnit that is acting up, but a local php configuration issue causing problems in your system under test? Diff your php.ini on the 2 machines and you will likely find some differences.